# Intercommunication between TCP  Servers in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, load-balancing

I have a application in which I am using socket programming , having this(image) scenario.
[image: Inter-server Communication]
Where number of clients will try to connect Broadcast server. 
Now here I am managing load through LVS(Load balancer). so as a example shown in image, suppose 200 clients will wish to login for broadcast they will be distributed as 100 users on server 1 and another 100 users on server 2.clients will get connected to servers using TCP connection.

Now I am maintaining user information on server side in arraylist  which will be stored in heap memory,Now the problem is if client wish to broadcast to all logged in users, but that particular client is logged in server 1. and so client will not be able to broadcast another 100 users from server 2.  Because both ther servers are unaware about each others state.

please suggest me to solve this scenario by whatever means you want.

Comment: Send message to the other servers and let them send the message to their users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the two servers log in to each other and arrange for broadcasts to be forwarded to the other server and then on to that server's clients.

Comment: This logic might  fail if we will add more servers.

Comment: Why? If each server has access to a list of all the servers and logs in to every other server except itself, tht should work, no?  Even if there is 128 servers, that's still only 128 client connections per server used for inter-server comms - plenty left for 'real' clients.  Alternatively, you could daisy-chain the server comms so that only one client connection is used per server.  These servers are on a local LAN, right?  You could use UDP broadcast or TCP multicast to distribute the broadcasts.  Maybe your servers are plugged into the same backplane and have a high-speed bus? I don't know..

Comment: or create a master server where all servers login and which distributes the requests to connected client-servers

Comment: @zapl - oh yeah, I forgot that one <g>

Comment: Thanks for solution  and it should work also. but when i get request from client server is creating new thread for each request. so for 1 client there is one thread.  (continue with below comment)

Comment: Now suppose there i will implement your logic and what i have to do is create one more thread for login into one more server, considering its only single added server(total servers are 2). so the number of threads are doubled which is reducing execution capacity of the server by double. i.e. suppose my server was able to handle 40k user requests simulteneously its now reduced to 20k.considering this there is no use of adding one more server for load balancing. May be i am missing something please consider my view and lets discuss on this..

Comment: NO, one extra login per server, not one login per client!  It logs in using a special account and uses a special protocol to forward messages for all clients that need it.